# ffmpeg via shell_exec not working

Tags: php, shell, ffmpeg

I'm running the following command in the console without any problems:

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/input.mp4 /var/www/html/output.mp3
```

But when I run the command in PHP, I get nothing:

```
<?php
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/input.mp4 /var/www/html/output.mp3");
?>
```

Any idea what the problem is here? I've checked my CHMOD permissions, everything looks good. Anything else to check?

Thank you,

Comment: What about it is not working correctly? Is there no output file or are you expecting something to come back in the PHP file?

Comment: You're not checking for any output or errors.  Start by looking into the stdout, stderr, and exit code if you're going to be running system commands.  If you don't know about those, time to start researching.

Comment: I'm not getting any output. I'll look into the error reporting. That should help a lot instead of blindly working

Answer (score 2):

I would try running it with full path to ffmpeg. You can get the full path on unix by running `which ffmpeg` in the command line. My ubuntu box produces output like `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`. Use that full path in code:

```
<?php
shell_exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/input.mp4 /var/www/html/output.mp3");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

For sure (as written above) passing full path is to exec is a good idea. Also you should also redirect the error stream to the output you gather - add the " 2>&1" to the end of the command. Take a look at the first comment [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#106250).